# Nvim - I don't understand how to change the options of this plugin

Tags: r, vim, vim-plugin, vim-r

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R/master/doc/Nvim-R.txt

Section 6 of that document, ctrlF + *Nvim-R-options*

I'm new to vim, not sure what to do with that information. I want to disable |R_assign|, or possibly reverse the way it works so a double underscore produces a <- in insert mode.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usually recommended method to disable is to add this line to your ~/.vimrc file:

```
let vimrplugin_assign = 0
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work (at least for me).

When you go through the .vim script files installed by the plugin, the answer lies in lines 2844-2847 of [common_global.vim](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R/blob/master/R/common_global.vim) file in the source code:

```
    " Replace 'underline' with '<-'
    if g:R_assign == 1 || g:R_assign == 2
        silent exe 'inoremap <buffer><silent> ' . g:R_assign_map . ' <Esc>:call ReplaceUnderS()<CR>a'
endif
```

So the real solution is to add this line to your ~/.vimrc file:

```
let R_assign = 0
```

An easy one-liner to do the job for you (if you use a Unix-like system):

```
echo "let R_assign = 0" >> ~/.vimrc
```

Do not forget to put two directions as ">>" in order to append and not replace.